# overlapping clothes

Tags: modeling, shrinkwrap

[image]

Is there any technique to procedurally solve the problem of overlapping clothes?

I thought I could solve it with Shrinkwrap to wrap the top clothes over the other one. It didn't work.

It almost worked to do the other way around: project the one below on the top one.

Is there a setting to Shrinkwrap that would do that?

Or is there a way to use the clothes above as some kind of bound?

[image]

this is the best I get with the shrinkwrap modifier.

Comment: I assume you have played with the Shrinkwrap "Offset" parameter?  And you can apply Shrinkwrap to vertex groups, so you could have differing offsets for shoulder-strap areas, etc.   Then you might want to "Apply" it once you're satisfied and ready to pose the character and animate the cloth.  Also, many Methods and Modes to experiment with.

Comment: Ah, yes I can use several Shrinkwrap modifiers with different vertex groups, it may get more accurate.
You say 'many methods and modes to experiment with', like what? Can you give some examples?  thnks